# Is there a Bash command to convert \r\n to \n?

Tags: linux, bash, newlines, carriage-return

Is there a Bash command to convert \r\n to \n?

When I upload my scripts from Windows to Linux, I need a utility like this to make things work.

Comment: `dos2unix` is usually available, otherwise `sed -e 's/\r$//'`

Comment: No, there's no Bash command for that, but there's `dos2unix` which is a Unix/Linux program to do what you want.

Comment: Why don't you just use a sane text editor that lets you choose newline style when saving files?

Answer (score 33):

There is:

```
dos2unix
```

Comment: This is the historically correct answer, though dos2unix is not always available these days.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Unix utility called `conv` that can convert line endings.  It is often invoked with softlinks to `u2d` or `d2u` or `unix2dos` or `dos2unix`.

Additionally there are utilities called `fromdos` and `todos`.

Answer (score 6):

Translate ([tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29)) is available in all Unixes:

```
tr -d '\r'  # From \r\n line end (DOS/Windows), the \r will be removed so \n line end (Unix) remains.
```

Comment: Has a side-effect of removing any other `\r`'s too. They're highly uncommon though.

Answer (score 5):

With sed and find that end with `.txt, .php, .js, .css`:

```
 sed -rie 's/\r\n/\n/' \
 $(find . -type f -iregex ".*\.\(txt\|php\|js\|css\)")
```

Answer (score 4):

Doing this with POSIX is tricky:

- [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) does not support `\r` or `\15`. Even if it did, the in place
  option `-i` is not POSIX
- [POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does support `\r` and `\15`, however the `-i inplace` option
  is not POSIX
- *d2u* and *dos2unix* are not [POSIX utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), but *ex* is
- [POSIX ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) does not support `\r`, `\15`, `\n` or `\12`

To remove carriage returns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

To add carriage returns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\n","\r&");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using man 1 ed (which edits files in-place without any previous backup - unlike: sed .. -i ".bak" ...):

```
ed -s file <<< $'H\ng/\r*$/s///\nwq'
```

Comment: I diden't even know ed,but it does the job (old but gold)

Comment: This command worked for me when commands from other answers did not exist on the shared hosting I am using. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `dos2unix`. For example:

```
[justin@mybox ~]$ dos2unix myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

> $ [recode](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/recode) dos.. FILE
>   $ [flip](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/flip) -u FILE

(Each also exists for non-Ubuntu systems, but these links are handy.)

Answer (score 0):

cat input.csv | sed 's/\r/\n/g' > output.csv

Comment: Some explanation and formatting would make this an answer. Right now it's just a comment.